# Extract Username and Password from Config file in Perl

Tags: perl, conditional-statements

I have written a Perl script which calls a Perl module called `getData.pm` to extract userid and password from configuration (data.txt) file.

Below are the scripts:
**main.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $server = $ARGV[0];

use getData;

print "*** SECUREUSER DETAILS ***\n";
my $access = "secure";
my ($node_user, $node_passwd) = getData::getUserPW($server,$access);

print "node_user: $node_user ** node_passwd:$node_passwd\n";

print "*** ROOTUSER DETAILS ***\n";
my $access = "root";
my ($node_user, $node_passwd) = getData::getUserPW($server,$access);

print "node_user: $node_user ** node_passwd:$node_passwd\n";
```

**getData.pm**

```
package getData;

sub getUserPW {
    my $ne = shift;
    my $access = shift;

    die "Two parameters are must.\n" unless ($ne && $access);

    my $filename = '/path/to/file/data.txt';
    open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
        or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

    my @words;

    while (my $row = <$fh>) {
        chomp $row;
        next if ($row =~ /^SERVER\s+USERTYPE\s+USERID\s+PASSWD$/);
        next unless (($row =~ /$ne/) && ($row =~ /$access/));
        
        @words = split / /, $row, 4;

        if( $ne eq $words[0]){
            return ($words[2], $words[3]);
        }
    }
    return;
}
1;
```

And below is my **data.txt** file contents:

```
SERVER USERTYPE USERID PASSWD
LTE01 secure user1 YAHfNy
LTE01 root user3 mXg5gP
LTE011 secure user2 YAHfNy
```

My input to the `main.pl` is SERVERNAME. Example LTE01.

My query here is - in `getData.pm` if below condition is TRUE then it means `$row` should have `$ne` and `$access` values, i.e., LTE01 and secure/root

```
next unless (($row =~ /$ne/) && ($row =~ /$access/));
```

But after this condition I have to split the row values to have the exact match to the SERVERNAME

```
if( $ne eq $words[0]){
```

Else, LTE01 and LTE0 will get matched in unless statement itself.

Is there any simplest way to achieve this without using 2 conditional statements?

Comment: You have more problems. What if a system's password is the name of another system? You're better off parsing the whole file into a data structure and looking up the credentials. Produce a structure like `$foo->{LTE01}->{secure} = [ 'user1', ' YAHfNy' ]` and then look up the thing you want.

Comment: The safest option would be to remove the regex check, since it is has multiple problems, and not needed in any case. Just split the line and check all fields with `eq`.

Comment: You should also always use `use strict; use warnings;`. Without exception, and especially when asking others for help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do to improve what you are doing.

First, don't do any checks until you've decomposed the line to its components. You don't want to accidentally find the server name in a different part of the line.

Second, giving names to the columns is much easier to understand:

```
use v5.10;

my $wanted_server = 'LTE011';

my( $user, $pass ) = get_user_pass( $wanted_server );
say "User: $user Pass: $pass";

sub get_user_pass {
    my( $wanted_server ) = @_;

    while (my $row = <DATA>) {
        chomp $row;
        my ( $server, $user, $user_id, $pass ) = split / /, $row, 4;
        return ( $user_id, $pass ) if $server eq $wanted_server;
        }

    return;
    }

__DATA__
SERVER USERTYPE USERID PASSWD
LTE01 secure user1 YAHfNy
LTE01 root user3 mXg5gP
LTE011 secure user2 YAHfNy
FAKE secure user2 LTE011
```